# edge Data labelling OSM local tile server

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, graph

i have OSM tile server running locally on my machine

I have used Leaflet to add markers

Now I am looking for graph script in which markers to act as nodes and polygon (more precisely an arc) to show edged data? is there any API available?

Comment: Maybe you should combine leaflet with D3.js. D3 allows you to manipulate easily vector graphics, while leaflet will be limited for that. Here is an introduction: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/

Comment: D3 doesn't provide that capabilities on Maps as far as i had searched and explored. But for people who might run into same need as i had, i used LINKURIOUS [link](http://linkurio.us/) to create graph and edges. it uses Sigma.js (high customization). Linkurious also have leaflet plugin. so overall awesome :)